# Unable to focus and select the last row in grid

Tags: extjs, extjs5

It worked great in `ExtJs 4.X`, however, it does not in `5.X`. This is what I do:

```
grid.getView().focusRow(rowIndex);
grid.getSelectionModel().select(rowIndex);
```

It is interesting, that if I set rowIndex to the index of the last but one row, then it successfully selects it and scrolls in the view. So, my question is, if it is possible to focus (select and scroll to) any grid row, including the last one?

Comment: Yes, possible: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/q96

Comment: `grid.getView().focusRow(499);
grid.getSelectionModel().select(499);`

Comment: This does not work in your example. Do you mean this?

Comment: In Chrome: http://screencast.com/t/1U9tXufV

Comment: If you test it in FF 39.0 (last version), then you will see, that it does not work. I mean the code from my second comment, where I use more general rowIndex, than a specific last() row.

Comment: In FF 39: http://screencast.com/t/oZyXpp2wh

Comment: From your screencast it is not clear, whether you use numeric rowIndex, or again last() row.

Comment: If you use numeric index, then I must confess, that there is something wrong with my FF build (and that is extremely strange).

Comment: works fine in chrome Version 43.0.2357.132 (64-bit)